# PHP test for 100 different types of input values

Tags: php

i am  getting input form form submission and depending on the user input which can be over 100 different types i want to do something what should i use to do this.

i am thinking about using switch case

```
switch( strtolower($value) ) {
 case "99": $url = "http://www.numericProcessor.com/"; break;
 case "ninetynine": $url = "http://www.alphabeticProcessor.com/"; break;
 default: $url = "/InvalidOption.html"; break;
}
```

Is the way to go? Or should i try something else?

What are its alternatives if any?

Comment: a switch with 100 cases sound wrong. Show some context please, right now your question doesn't make that much sense

Comment: say i am doing a search from 100 different web-sites and when the user sends the selected site i want the user to be redirected to that site so how do i sort which of the 100 options the user has selected?

Comment: Sounds like a dictionary of site, url might do the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create table with columns: id, value, url. Select all values from table as array(SELECT value, url FROM your_table). Example array:

```
// data from your table. value => url
$urls = [
    0 => '/InvalidOption.html', //default
    1 => 'url1',
    ....
    99 => 'http://www.numericProcessor.com/'
];

if (isset($urls[$value])) {
   $url = $urls[$value];
} else {
   url = $urls[0]; // default url
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with array_search;

```
$options = array(
  'what ever' => '99'
  'what else' => '22'
);

$value = array_search(strtolower($value), $options);
```